# Can't use dapper to multimap a one-to-many pair of tables with composite primary key

Tags: one-to-many, dapper, multi-mapping

I'm looking into dapper for an application with lots of readonly data. For explanation purposes, I've got 2 tables: Car and Wheel with a one-to-many relationship between the two. The Car table has CarID as a primary key, Wheel has a composite primary key existing of CarID and WheelIndex. I've tried the following code to retrieve all cars, with links to the wheels as follows:

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public List<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; } = new List<Wheel>();
    ...
}

public class Wheel
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public int WheelIndex { get; set; }
    ...
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionstring = "{insert connection string}";
    var query = "SELECT C.CarID, WheelIndex FROM Car C JOIN Wheel W ON C.CarId = W.CarId";
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring)){
        var cars = connection.Query<Car, Wheel, Car>(query, (car, wheel) =>
        {
            car.Wheels.Add(wheel);
            return car;
        }, splitOn: "WheelIndex");
    }
}
```

This however only returns each combination of cars with one wheel in the Wheels list. Anybody has any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure I'm just missing something.

EDIT: For reasons I can't fully disclose, Entity Framework is not a viable option.

Comment: Dapper is a light weight orm, maybe you should try EF core

Comment: hi NBK, thanks for the tip, but for reasons I'm not sure I can disclose, EF is not a viable option. I'll adjust my question to display this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely do it in the query, there is no need to afterburn the data.

Here is how:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionstring = "{insert connection string}";
    var query = "SELECT C.CarID, WheelIndex FROM Car C JOIN Wheel W ON C.CarId = W.CarId";
    var cars = new Dictionary<int, Car>();
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        connection.Query<Car, Wheel, Car>(query, (c, w) =>
        {
            if (!cars.TryGetValue(c.Id, out Car car))
            {
                // Car wasn't found in the dictionary
                car = c;
                cars.Add(car.id, car);
            }
            cars[c.Id].Wheels.Add(w);
            return null; // You won't need this. the result is in cars.
        }, splitOn: "WheelIndex");
    }
    // Use cars ...
}
```

That's pretty much the standard way of transforming your 2-dimensional Dapper/ADO result set into a hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes so much more sense this way as well. Could you just remove the assigment of the cars dictionary on line 8? As it's impossible and not necessary if it were. Tried to do it myself, but stackoverflow kept popping up a message saying "edit queue is full".

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste error.